# Windows Server 2012 running at low Maximum Frequency even under full load

Tags: cpu, windows-server-2012-r2

A Windows 2012 Server (system specs below) is running at 0-20% Max Frequency only despite being under full load, CPU usage constantly at >=100%. (according to Ressource Monitor, picture below). Why is is not going to 100% Max Frequency? I feel i'm not getting the full processing power.

Power Plan is set to High Performance.

[Ressource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IP1w.png)

[Server specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMnb.png)

Comment: Looks like java's just a low priority, and doesn't warrant speeding up over. But how are the temperatures?

Comment: temperatures according to HWMonitor between 35 and 40.

Comment: Priority raised from normal to real-time, but no different behavior

Comment: What are you using to monitor the frequency, and is it accurate? Does the priority you changed (in resource monitor?) make a difference to the frequency governor? Is it a 3rd party program controlling the frequency?

Comment: I only use the Windows Resource Monitor to monitor the Frequency. Is that not reliable? On other servers I always get stable 100% Maximum Frequencies when under full load.

Comment: No 3rd party program is controlling the frequency. It is a fresh Windows installation with only the Java program and HWMonitor installed as external programs.